# Sequelize - Please install mysql2 package manually

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have created a separate **helper library** to work with databases.

I am then importing this library in my project. When I am trying to create a db connection using mysql dialect, it says the following: `Please install mysql2 package manually`

I have installed **mysql2** library in my **root project** but it still does not work. Do I have to install mysql2 in the **helper library** as well ? Is there any way to install a dependency to be visible in other libraries as well ?

I am trying to keep it as small as possible. I want the library to be configurable from the root application.

Answer (score 10):

I found the solution. **Sequelize** accepts the dialect option in the constructor. All you need to do is provide it:

```js
const connection = new Sequelize({
    host: 'localhost',
    username: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'mydb',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    dialectModule: require('mysql2'), <========= IMPORTING DIALECT
    benchmark: true
})
```